# Industrial Level Applications. Recipe for mixed notation of equations set

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, symbolic

I am working with large (linear) equations set within Mathematica in numerical notation. For example, set from 4056 eq. is solved for a second, no more. There is no doubt, result is great. But even simple mixed (both numeric and symbolic) data in 5-20 equation set is the problem... What is the reason? And what the way to solve it? Is it necessary to filter (provide) all data to symbolic form. Data are presented by three forms: 23.234 (float), 23/11 (aka fraction), F/w (symbolic).

**Example**

```
Equations = {c1bXZ[1] - c1bXZ[2] + c1bXZ[5] == (-1)*0, -c1bXZ[1] + 
c1bXZ[3] + c1bXZ[4] == (-1)*0, 
c1bXZ[2] == (-1)*RX[3], -c1bXZ[3] == (-1)*
RX[4], -c1bXZ[4] == (-1)*0, -c1bXZ[5] == (-1)*F, -c1bYZ[1] + 
c1bYZ[2] + c1sStr[5] == (-1)*0, -1000 + c1bYZ[1] - c1bYZ[3] + 
c1sStr[4] == (-1)*0, -c1bYZ[2] == (-1)*RY[3], 
c1bYZ[3] == (-1)*
RY[4], -c1sStr[4] == (-1)*0, -c1sStr[5] == (-1)*0, -c1bYZ[5] - 
c1sStr[1] + c1sStr[2] == (-1)*0, -c1bYZ[4] + c1sStr[1] - 
c1sStr[3] == (-1)*0, -c1sStr[2] == (-1)*RZ[3], 
c1sStr[3] == (-1)*RZ[4], c1bYZ[4] == (-1)*0, c1bYZ[5] == (-1)*0, 
c1bYZ[2] - c2bYZ[1] + c2bYZ[2] - c2bYZ[5] == 
0, -500 + c1bYZ[1] + c2bYZ[1] - c2bYZ[3] - c2bYZ[4] == 
0, -c2bYZ[2] == 0, c1bYZ[3] + c2bYZ[3] == 0, 
c1bYZ[4] + c2bYZ[4] == 0, c1bYZ[5] + c2bYZ[5] == 0, 
c1bXZ[2] - c1tTor[5] - c2bXZ[1] + c2bXZ[2] == 0, 
c1bXZ[1] - c1tTor[4] + c2bXZ[1] - c2bXZ[3] == 0, -c2bXZ[2] == 0, 
c1bXZ[3] + c2bXZ[3] == 0, 200 + c1tTor[4] == 0, 
200 + c1tTor[5] == 0, 
c1tTor[1] - c1tTor[2] - c2bXZ[5] == 
0, -c1tTor[1] + c1tTor[3] - c2bXZ[4] == 0, 
c1tTor[2] == MZ[3], -c1tTor[3] == MZ[4], 
200 + c1bXZ[4] + c2bXZ[4] == 0, -200 + c1bXZ[5] + c2bXZ[5] == 
0, -c4bXZ[2] == 
0, (-c1bXZ[3] - 3*c2bXZ[3] - 2400000*c3bXZ[3])/2400000 - 
c4bXZ[3] == 0, 
c4bYZ[2] == 
0, (c1bYZ[3] + 3*c2bYZ[3] + 2400000*c3bYZ[3])/2400000 + c4bYZ[3] ==
0, -c2sStr[2] == 0, -c1sStr[3]/2000000000 - c2sStr[3] == 
0, -c4bXZ[1] == (-c1bXZ[2] - 3*c2bXZ[2] - 2400000*c3bXZ[2])/
 2400000 - 
c4bXZ[2], (-c1bXZ[2] - 3*c2bXZ[2] - 2400000*c3bXZ[2])/2400000 - 
c4bXZ[2] == -c4bXZ[
 5], (-c1bXZ[1] - 3*c2bXZ[1] - 2400000*c3bXZ[1])/2400000 - 
c4bXZ[1] == -c4bXZ[3], -c4bXZ[3] == -c4bXZ[4], 
c4bYZ[1] == (c1bYZ[2] + 3*c2bYZ[2] + 2400000*c3bYZ[2])/2400000 + 
c4bYZ[2], (c1bYZ[2] + 3*c2bYZ[2] + 2400000*c3bYZ[2])/2400000 + 
c4bYZ[2] == 
c2sStr[5], (-250 + c1bYZ[1] + 3*c2bYZ[1] + 2400000*c3bYZ[1])/
 2400000 + c4bYZ[1] == c4bYZ[3], 
c4bYZ[3] == 
c2sStr[4], -c2sStr[1] == -c1sStr[2]/2000000000 - 
c2sStr[2], -c1sStr[2]/2000000000 - c2sStr[2] == 
c4bYZ[5], -c1sStr[1]/2000000000 - 
c2sStr[1] == -c2sStr[3], -c2sStr[3] == c4bYZ[4], -c2tTor[2] == 
0, -c1tTor[3]/140000 - c2tTor[3] == 0, 
c3bYZ[1] == (c1bYZ[2] + 2*c2bYZ[2])/800000 + 
c3bYZ[2], (c1bYZ[2] + 2*c2bYZ[2])/800000 + c3bYZ[2] == 
c3bYZ[5], (-1000 + 3*c1bYZ[1] + 6*c2bYZ[1])/2400000 + c3bYZ[1] == 
c3bYZ[3], c3bYZ[3] == c3bYZ[4], 
c3bXZ[1] == (c1bXZ[2] + 2*c2bXZ[2])/800000 + 
c3bXZ[2], (c1bXZ[2] + 2*c2bXZ[2])/800000 + c3bXZ[2] == 
c2tTor[5], (c1bXZ[1] + 2*c2bXZ[1])/800000 + c3bXZ[1] == c3bXZ[3], 
c3bXZ[3] == 
c2tTor[4], -c2tTor[1] == -c1tTor[2]/140000 - 
c2tTor[2], -c1tTor[2]/140000 - c2tTor[2] == 
c3bXZ[5], -c1tTor[1]/140000 - 
c2tTor[1] == -c2tTor[3], -c2tTor[3] == c3bXZ[4]}
```

And Unknowns:

```
Unknows = {c1bXZ[1], c1bXZ[2], c1bXZ[3], c1bXZ[4], c1bXZ[5], c2bXZ[1],
c2bXZ[2], c2bXZ[3], c2bXZ[4], c2bXZ[5], c3bXZ[1], c3bXZ[2], 
c3bXZ[3], c3bXZ[4], c3bXZ[5], c4bXZ[1], c4bXZ[2], c4bXZ[3], 
c4bXZ[4], c4bXZ[5], c1bYZ[1], c1bYZ[2], c1bYZ[3], c1bYZ[4], 
c1bYZ[5], c2bYZ[1], c2bYZ[2], c2bYZ[3], c2bYZ[4], c2bYZ[5], 
c3bYZ[1], c3bYZ[2], c3bYZ[3], c3bYZ[4], c3bYZ[5], c4bYZ[1], 
c4bYZ[2], c4bYZ[3], c4bYZ[4], c4bYZ[5], c1sStr[1], c1sStr[2], 
c1sStr[3], c1sStr[4], c1sStr[5], c2sStr[1], c2sStr[2], c2sStr[3], 
c2sStr[4], c2sStr[5], c1tTor[1], c1tTor[2], c1tTor[3], c1tTor[4], 
c1tTor[5], c2tTor[1], c2tTor[2], c2tTor[3], c2tTor[4], c2tTor[5], 
RX[3], RY[3], RZ[3], RX[4], RY[4], RZ[4], MZ[3], MZ[4]}
```

I see hard work of processor in Mathematica without any result

And momentary result from Maple:

```
{MZ[3] = -200/3+(2/3)*F, MZ[4] = 200/3+(1/3)*F, RX[3] = -(2/3)*F+400/3, RX[4] = -(1/3)*F-400/3, RY[3] = 500, RY[4] = 500, RZ[3] = 0, RZ[4] = 0, c1bXZ[1] = -(1/3)*F-400/3, c1bXZ[2] = (2/3)*F-400/3, c1bXZ[3] = -(1/3)*F-400/3, c1bXZ[4] = 0, c1bXZ[5] = F, c1bYZ[1] = 500, c1bYZ[2] = 500, c1bYZ[3] = -500, c1bYZ[4] = 0, c1bYZ[5] = 0, c1sStr[1] = 0, c1sStr[2] = 0, c1sStr[3] = 0, c1sStr[4] = 0, c1sStr[5] = 0, c1tTor[1] = 400/3-(1/3)*F, c1tTor[2] = -200/3+(2/3)*F, c1tTor[3] = -200/3-(1/3)*F, c1tTor[4] = -200, c1tTor[5] = -200, c2bXZ[1] = (2/3)*F+200/3, c2bXZ[2] = 0, c2bXZ[3] = (1/3)*F+400/3, c2bXZ[4] = -200, c2bXZ[5] = 200-F, c2bYZ[1] = 500, c2bYZ[2] = 0, c2bYZ[3] = 500, c2bYZ[4] = 0, c2bYZ[5] = 0, c2sStr[1] = 0, c2sStr[2] = 0, c2sStr[3] = 0, c2sStr[4] = -11/9600, c2sStr[5] = -11/9600, c2tTor[1] = -1/2100+(1/210000)*F, c2tTor[2] = 0, c2tTor[3] = 1/2100+(1/420000)*F, c2tTor[4] = (1/1440000)*F-1/12000, c2tTor[5] = -(1/1800000)*F-1/12000, c3bXZ[1] = -(1/1800000)*F-1/12000, c3bXZ[2] = 1/12000-(1/720000)*F, c3bXZ[3] = (1/1440000)*F-1/12000, c3bXZ[4] = -1/2100-(1/420000)*F, c3bXZ[5] = 1/2100-(1/210000)*F, c3bYZ[1] = -7/9600, c3bYZ[2] = -13/9600, c3bYZ[3] = 7/9600, c3bYZ[4] = 7/9600, c3bYZ[5] = -7/9600, c4bXZ[1] = 1/36000-(1/900000)*F, c4bXZ[2] = 0, c4bXZ[3] = -(7/7200000)*F-1/36000, c4bXZ[4] = -(7/7200000)*F-1/36000, c4bXZ[5] = 1/36000-(1/900000)*F, c4bYZ[1] = -11/9600, c4bYZ[2] = 0, c4bYZ[3] = -11/9600, c4bYZ[4] = 0, c4bYZ[5] = 0}
```

By the word, Maple is more worse in numeric power.

Last example was very simple. 
The simple example where I can not to get symbolic solution here
[Equation set solution problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15392/still-can-not-to-solve-equation-set)

Comment: Could you provide a minimal "model" example showing some time difference? It is hard to give advise without seeing code.

Comment: It is not easy to do it within a comment. Where I can provide full example?

Comment: I was hoping for a small prototype example, not the whole thing.

Comment: I will place it within question.

Comment: I think you forgot to put actual code that solves this. What functions are you using?

Comment: For this notation Solve[Equations, Unknows]

Comment: Yet one thing Vitaliy. I work with numeric data also. What is the way to translate phrase -1.5E+04 in valid Mathematica Input Form notation?

Comment: Maybe `WolframAlpha["-1.5E+04", "Result"]` ?

Comment: The problem is at building construction (http://www.orlovsoft.com/Silverlight.html#/Screenshots) some data are presented in notation like this -1.5E+04 (-15000). But I can not find any way within Mathematica (NET Link API) to translate it to valid expression.

Comment: I would recommend asking this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica) or posting it as separate question to avoid piling up comments.

Comment: These equations look automatically generated. Couldn't you just create a matrix/vector and pass them to `LinearSolve`?

Comment: What is the way to get matrix form of such set? Analyse each coefficient at variable?

Comment: Do you generate the equations in code? If so, it might be more or less straightforward to generate a matrix instead.

Comment: Yes, in code. It works on the fly. My program analyses construction and put on stack equations. I even do not know dimension of possible future matrix. Of course, I can build a matrix, but analysis equations and collecting coefficients is hard process. There is no something like this BuildMatrix[EquationSet]...

Comment: I mean a size of future matrix.

Comment: maybe `CoefficientArrays` is useful

Comment: To expand on a very useful comment from @acl, CoefficientArrays can be used to get a matrix/vector form from the list of equations.

Comment: Again. Thanks for acl!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What specifically did you do? I seem to obtain a solution quickly.

```
In[8]:= InputForm[Timing[soln=Solve[Equations,Unknows]]]

(* Out[8]//InputForm= 
{0.02000000000000000041633363423443370266`4.321629908943605, 
 {{c1bXZ[1] -> (-400 - F)/3, c1bXZ[2] -> -400/3 + (2*F)/3, 
   c1bXZ[3] -> -400/3 - F/3, c1bXZ[4] -> 0, c1bXZ[5] -> F, 
   c2bXZ[1] -> 200/3 + (2*F)/3, c2bXZ[2] -> 0, c2bXZ[3] -> 400/3 + F/3, 
   c2bXZ[4] -> -200, c2bXZ[5] -> 200 - F, c3bXZ[1] -> -1/12000 - F/1800000, 
   c3bXZ[2] -> 1/12000 - F/720000, c3bXZ[3] -> -1/12000 + F/1440000, 
   c3bXZ[4] -> -1/2100 - F/420000, c3bXZ[5] -> 1/2100 - F/210000, 
   c4bXZ[1] -> 1/36000 - F/900000, c4bXZ[2] -> 0, 
   c4bXZ[3] -> -1/36000 - (7*F)/7200000, 
   c4bXZ[4] -> -1/36000 - (7*F)/7200000, c4bXZ[5] -> 1/36000 - F/900000, 
   c1bYZ[1] -> 500, c1bYZ[2] -> 500, c1bYZ[3] -> -500, c1bYZ[4] -> 0, 
   c1bYZ[5] -> 0, c2bYZ[1] -> 500, c2bYZ[2] -> 0, c2bYZ[3] -> 500, 
   c2bYZ[4] -> 0, c2bYZ[5] -> 0, c3bYZ[1] -> -7/9600, c3bYZ[2] -> -13/9600, 
   c3bYZ[3] -> 7/9600, c3bYZ[4] -> 7/9600, c3bYZ[5] -> -7/9600, 
   c4bYZ[1] -> -11/9600, c4bYZ[2] -> 0, c4bYZ[3] -> -11/9600, c4bYZ[4] -> 0, 
   c4bYZ[5] -> 0, c1sStr[1] -> 0, c1sStr[2] -> 0, c1sStr[3] -> 0, 
   c1sStr[4] -> 0, c1sStr[5] -> 0, c2sStr[1] -> 0, c2sStr[2] -> 0, 
   c2sStr[3] -> 0, c2sStr[4] -> -11/9600, c2sStr[5] -> -11/9600, 
   c1tTor[1] -> 400/3 - F/3, c1tTor[2] -> -200/3 + (2*F)/3, 
   c1tTor[3] -> -200/3 - F/3, c1tTor[4] -> -200, c1tTor[5] -> -200, 
   c2tTor[1] -> -1/2100 + F/210000, c2tTor[2] -> 0, 
   c2tTor[3] -> 1/2100 + F/420000, c2tTor[4] -> -1/12000 + F/1440000, 
   c2tTor[5] -> -1/12000 - F/1800000, RX[3] -> 400/3 - (2*F)/3, RY[3] -> 500, 
   RZ[3] -> 0, RX[4] -> -400/3 - F/3, RY[4] -> 500, RZ[4] -> 0, 
   MZ[3] -> -200/3 + (2*F)/3, MZ[4] -> 200/3 + F/3}}} *)
```

Comment: Sorry, it works... The reason is I prepare data programmatically and forgot something at copy-paste... I hope the TIMO Structural 2.0 (Mathematica) will with full symbolic notation http://www.orlovsoft.com/Silverlight.html#/Screenshots