How to solve a linear equation set in matrix form?
I am trying to solve a linear equation set in the matrix form. For example, A={x+y,x-y},B={2,0}, the equation is {x+y,x-y}=={2,0}, or A==B. I would like to know how to solve a equation in this form. I tried to use Solve[{x+y,x-y}=={2,0},{x,y}] which doesn't work. I don't want to solve the equation in the form of $mv=b$ where v={x,y};b={2,0};m={{1,1},{1,-1}}, because it's very difficult to transform my data into this form.

A={x+y,x-y};B={2,0};Reduce[A==B,{x,y}] returns x==1&&y==1 If that isn't the form of result that you want then please show exactly the result that you want.

Works for me. `In[1317]:= Solve[{x + y, x - y} == {2, 0}, {x, y}]
Out[1317]= {{x -> 1, y -> 1}}`

See also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15395/1871

"I tried to use Solve[{x+y,x-y}=={2,0},{x,y}] which doesn't work." This should not happen, the syntax is supported at least since version 1.2: https://i.sstatic.net/9nmONrAK.png

Is this what you want?
A[x_, y_] := {x + y, x - y}
B = {2, 0};
Solve[A[x, y] == B, {x, y}]



A = {x + y, x - y};
b = {2, 0};

Determine the list of variables:
vars = Variables[A]
(*    {x, y}    *)

Convert the equations into matrix form: this is the step you say is difficult; but it's actually quite trivial,
M = D[A, {vars}]
(*    {{1, 1}, {1, -1}}    *)

Check that we did it right:
M . vars == A
(*    True    *)

The equations are now
M . vars == b
(*    {x + y, x - y} == {2, 0}    *)

and we can solve them with LinearSolve or the more general LeastSquares:
s = LinearSolve[M, b]
(*    {1, 1}    *)

If you want the solution as a replacement list:
Thread[vars -> s]
(*    {x -> 1, y -> 1}    *)

